# IntelliJ module dependencies getting removed

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module

Searching Google about this problem gives me lots of questions on removing dependencies, but that's not my problem.

In IntelliJ, I add dependencies between modules via the module settings. However, when I add something to Maven, all those module dependencies are being removed. I don't want them removed. I put them there for a reason!

What do I have to do to get it to stop?

Comment: Are you referencing the parent pom in the dependencies? Also, what's the packaging of your parent?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Maven synchronization is one way, every change you make in the dependencies and project structure will be discarded on the next Maven project reimport. It's by design. The changes should go into pom.xml instead.